# Maintain seperate files for popup forms or loop fields conditionally on a single file in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am complete beginner to react js. At the moment, I am having trouble deciding the best approach.

**#Current Approach**

I have a popup which is triggered on clicking vertically aligned divs. So these popups are forms with fields that may be same for some forms.

So I have an array that have the attributes of fields (names, classes) which I loop based on the clicked div id and display the form. So I have only one file in which the array is looped and displayed based on the clicked DIV.

**#Question**

My confusion is should I write popup forms for each div in separate files as class components and call them conditionally ? Or should I follow the current approach ?

Answer (score 1):

If set of form fields is fixed , Approach #Current Approach is good,
But use some prop like 'set_type' instead of div 'id' to filter the list

Comment: The form fields are fixed. I will use some props as you suggested. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the current approach.

because you will use the same code even if in the future you have to add more forms and only you will update the array. (its know as a re-usable component)

but if you create separate files for each form, in the future if you want to add more forms, you have to create a component which is exactly the same as the previous component except the component name. and you are adding repeating code. and you are making your folder structures bulkier too by adding files.

so DRY concept fails over here. (Don't repeat yourself)

Comment: I had kept that in my mind while implementing the current approach. Thanks for the help.